# Relationship among the function spaces $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ and $C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, notation

I have seen the spaces $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ and $C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$ a lot in theorems regarding PDE where $\Omega$ denotes some  open subset of $\Bbb{R}^d$. There is no doubt about the definitions of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$. But I'm not very clear about the relationships among these three spaces.

Here are my **questions**:

- What is the definition for $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$? If one says it consists of functions $f:\overline{\Omega}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f$ is smooth (infinitely differentiable) and with compact support, my question concerns the value of $f$ on $\partial\Omega\setminus\Omega$. (I would really appreciate if one could also come up with a reference for definiton of this space. )
- Could one come up with an example illustrating the difference between $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ and $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$?
- Are $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ and $C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$ "essentially" the same? If so, how? (I've seen these two spaces in different books regarding a same theorem.)

---

[Added:]
In the book *[Navier-Stokes Equations--- Theory and Numerical Analysis](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CHEL-343-H)* by Temam, the author defines (page 3)

> $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ (or $\mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega})$) be the space of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support contained in $\Omega$ (or $\overline{\Omega}$).

I have replaced the symbol $\mathcal{D}$ with $C_c^\infty$ here.

Comment: Can you please write where have you seen $C^{\infty}_c(\overline{\Omega})$ used?

Comment: Are you sure about $C_c^\infty (\overline {\Omega}) $? Maybe you are confusing it with $C^\infty (\overline {\Omega}) $?

Comment: @levap: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that the author of the book doesn't explicitly define what it means for a function defined on a closed set to be differentiable, I can only guess that for him differentiable functions on a closed set are restrictions of differentiable functions defined on a larger, open set and so

$$ \mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega}) = \{ f \colon \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \, | \, \exists g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{ s.t } f = g|_{\overline{\Omega}}, \mathrm{supp}_{\overline{\Omega}} f \subset \subset \overline{\Omega} \}. $$

Using this definition, we have $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \subset \mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega}) \subset C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. To see the difference between $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega})$, take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ smooth with compact support such that $g(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Then $g \notin \mathcal{D}((0,1))$ but $g \in \mathcal{D}([0,1])$. More generally, one can characterize $\mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega})$ as

$$ \mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega}) = \{ f \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \, | \, \exists g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{ s.t } f = g|_{\Omega}, \,\, \mathrm{supp}_{\mathbb{R}^n} g \subset \subset \mathbb{R}^n \} $$

so that functions in $\mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega})$ are restrictions to $\Omega$ of functions in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I've found your notation $C^{\infty}_c(\overline{\Omega})$ used together with the latter definition in [*Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains* (page 24)](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=LdMk297ExhkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Pierre Grisvard.

If $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) = \mathcal{D}(\overline{\Omega})$ as the notation suggests.